# Coldfusion Deserializing json from cfhttp that is query driven

Tags: mysql, json, coldfusion

I am trying to loop through a search api for some data.  I am wrapping the cfhttp with a cfoutput to place a query field in place of a url variable.  The cfhttp and cfoutput are working.  My query is limited to 5 and I am getting the five I expect at this point in the code.  The part I am having trouble with is the deserializing and dumping.  The cfdump is only dumping the last result.

Here is my code:

```
<cfquery name="gameName" datasource="UNOBerry">
Select replace(g.GameTitle, ' ', '+') as GameTitle
From Games g
where left(g.gametitle,1) = 'h'
limit 5
</cfquery>

<cfoutput query="gameName">
    <cfhttp url="https://ahmedakhan-game-review-information-v1.p.mashape.com/api/v1/information?game_name=#gameName.GameTitle#" method="get" resolveurl="Yes" throwOnError="Yes">
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="X-Mashape-Key" value="api-key" >
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Accept" value="application/json" >
    </cfhttp>

    #CFHTTP.FileContent#<br />
</cfoutput>

<cfset cfData=DeserializeJSON(CFHTTP.FileContent)> 

<cfdump var="#cfData#">

<cfoutput>#cfData#</cfoutput>
```

Json Example:

```
{"result":{"websites":["metacritic","ign"],"genre":["Action","Third-Person Shooter"],"developer":["SOF Studios"],"availablePlatform":[],"publisher":["SOF Studios"],"averageScore":null,"gamespot":{"userScore":0,"criticScore":0,"url":"could not find game on gamespot"},"gamesradar":{"criticScore":0,"url":"could not find game on gamesradar"},"metacritic":{"criticScore":"","userScore":"91","url":"http://www.metacritic.com/game/pc/h-hour-worlds-elite"},"name":"H-Hour: World's Elite","platform":"PC","thumbnail":"http://static.metacritic.com/images/products/games/6/bfa7f045464f857c09b058ef3bc798b8-98.jpg","rating":"","rlsdate":"TBA - Early Access","ign":{"criticScore":"-.-","userScore":"10","url":"http://www.ign.com/games/h-hour/pc-20000494"}}}
```

In reality my end goal is to get this into a usable json file that i import into my database.  So if I am going about this in the completely wrong way feel free to put me in my place.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You need to have code that relates to each iteration of the loop *inside the loop* not outside it. Also recommend using `<cfloop`> for looping, and restrict `<cfoutput>` usage to simple output: it's more semantically appropriate. But that said... also recommend not writing code like this using tags at all.